# Some features disappearing when zooming out in QGIS

Tags: qgis, zoom, display

When zooming out on the canvas, some features of a polygon layer (within a geopackage) are disappearing from the canvas, but not all. They reappear when zoomed in. I have checked scale dependent visibility and geometry for the layer, but neither of these seem to be the issue.

Any advice on how to solve this please?

Comment: I remember a weird behavior when a polygon is not entirely inside the canvas it disappears completely. Could that be it? Especially if it is a multipolygon.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Pics would be nice.

Comment: Sample project + data could help as well